# Problema basico para python

Tags: python

Mi problema es que no se hacer que la respuesta que se hace en la pregunta numero 5. salga en una parte de otra pregunta que seria la 6.

> Ejemplo: En la 5. pregunta respondo Argentina, quiero que en la siguiente pregunta salga "De que ciudad de Argentina eres?" eso seria.

```
# Introduccion

print("Autor: Dragoniux")
print("--Primer test con Python--")
print(input("Preciona enter para continuar..."))

# Preguntas :D

1. nombreapellido = print(input("Cual es tu nombre y apellido? "))
2. añodenacimiento = print(input("En que año nacistes? "))
3. edad = print(input("Cuantos años tienes? "))
4. color = print(input("Cual es tu color favorito? "))
5. pais = print(input("De que pais eres? "))
6. ciudad = print(input("De que ciudad de {pais} eres? "))
```

Comment: Esto te ayudará hermano: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/pythonya/ ¡buenas vibras con el desarrollo!

Answer (score 2):

No te preocupes Lucas, es sencillo pero con algo se empieza.
La respuesta sería utilizando la función format y quitando los print:

```
pais = input("De que pais eres? ")
ciudad = input("De que ciudad de {} eres? ".format(pais))
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, te comento que ésta construcción es errónea para lo que buscas:

```
nombreapellido = print(input("Cual es tu nombre y apellido? "))
```

`input()` pedirá un entrada por teclado (Python 3.x únicamente), la salida luego es impresa mediante el `print()` pero éste solo retorna `None` por consiguiente no asignas ninguna variable, lo correcto eventualmente, es hacer esto en cada caso:

```
nombreapellido = input("Cual es tu nombre y apellido? ")
print(nombreapellido)
```

Con respecto a imprimir la variable junto con el texto, además de usar la función `format()` que ya te han comentado, si estuvieras utilizando python 3.6 o superior, puedes usar directamente las `f'strings` que son cadenas especiales que se interpretan automáticamente, se implementaron en la [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) y son muy sencillas de utilizar:

```
pais = input("De que pais eres? ")
ciudad = input(f"De que ciudad de {pais} eres? ")
```